# How to check index in MongoDB C# (existing or not) as IndexExist is deprecated from newer version

Tags: c#, mongodb

I just updated the old MongoDB C# drivers to `2.7.3` version and after updating it from nuget packages i got lot of errors line

> EnsureIndex is not defined

and

> IndexExists not defined
>
> ping is not defined

and

> getServer is not defined

so is their and update document or documentation which will explain how to get these with a newer version.

```
var connectionString = string.Format("mongodb://{0}:{1}", mongoServerInstance.Address.Host, mongoServerInstance.Address.Port);
            connectionString = ReplaceHostNames(connectionString);
            _logger.Debug("checking for indexes on server, {0}", mongoServerInstance.Address.Host);
            var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
            settings.ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct;
            settings.ReadPreference = ReadPreference.SecondaryPreferred;
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
            var listMongo = mongoClient.ListDatabases();
            var server = mongoClient.GetServer();

            foreach (var index in MongoRepositoryConfiguration.Indexes)
            {
                var mongoDataBase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(index.DatabaseName);

                if (!mongoClient.GetDatabase(index.DatabaseName)
                            .GetCollection<BsonDocument>(index.CollectionName)
                            .IndexExists(index.MongoIndexKeys))
                {
                    if (index.IndexName != "")
                    {
                        if (!mongoClient.GetDatabase(index.DatabaseName)
                                   .GetCollection<BsonDocument>(index.CollectionName)
                                   .IndexExistsByName(index.IndexName))
                        {
                            AddIndexToList(index, nonExistentIndexes);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddIndexToList(index, nonExistentIndexes);
                    }
                }
            }

            server.Disconnect();
```

Answer (score 3):

in 2.x driver you can get details of indexes for a given collection via the `collection.Indexes.List()` method. here's an example of creating two indexes and getting their names using [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) [disclaimer: i'm the author]

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class User : Entity
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            DB.Index<User>()
              .Key(u => u.FirstName, KeyType.Text)
              .Key(u => u.LastName, KeyType.Text)
              .Create();

            DB.Index<User>()
              .Key(u => u.Age, KeyType.Ascending)
              .Create();

            var indexes = DB.Collection<User>().Indexes.List().ToList();

            foreach (var index in indexes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(index.GetElement("name"));
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you please explain how to check connect or disconnect or ping the server as server.Reconnect and Disconnect are undefined.

Comment: with the latest driver you don't need to manually handle connection/re-connection/re-try etc. you just perform an action and handle any exceptions it throws. things are much easier and streamlined now.

Answer (score 1):

For using in **C#** with the *nuget package* **MongoDB.Driver V 2.14.1** I created an extension method for **IMongoCollection** to check, wether an index for a given name already exists in that collection:

```
public static bool HasIndex<T>(this IMongoCollection<T> mongoCollection, string indexName)
{
    var indexes = mongoCollection.Indexes.List().ToList();
    var indexNames = indexes
        .SelectMany(i => i.Elements)
        .Where(e => string.Equals(e.Name, "name", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Select(n => n.Value.ToString()).ToList();

    return indexNames.Contains(indexName);
}
```

So whenever you want to check if an index exists in a specific collection of a mongo database you can check it via this example:

```
var database = _mongoClient.GetDatabase("Database");
var examples = database.GetCollection<Example>("Examples");

var hasIndex = examples.HasIndex("ExampleIndex");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for index already exists and then create one

```
var db = _mongoClient.GetDatabase("db");
var coll = db.GetCollection<Coll>("collName");
var indexes = (await (await coll.Indexes.ListAsync()).ToListAsync()).Select(_ => _.GetElement("name").Value.ToString()).ToList();
// If index not present create it else skip.
if (indexes.Where(_ => _.Equals("<Index Name>")).Count() == 0)
{
    // Create Index here
}
```